# Import class from a package at higher level but with the name of a package at same level in Scala

Tags: scala, import, namespaces, package

I've got a packages structure that's like this:

```
src/main
- java
-- pk0
-- pk1
--- pk10
--- pk11
---- class0.scala
---- util
-- util
- scala
-- pk0
-- pk1
--- pk10
--- pk11
---- class0.scala
---- pk12
--- ...
-- util
--- utilClass.scala
```

In `class0.scala` I want to import `utilClass.scala` so I do this with

```
import util.utilClass
```

but it tells me that `Cannot resolve symbol classUtil`. If I try to execute, it tells me `object utilClass is not a member of package pk11.util`. I cannot resolve this, it seems to me I made a good use of namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this calling `_root_.util.utilClass`.